# Highcharts border around plot

Tags: jquery, highcharts

So I am trying to make a highchart that looks like this:

[image: Desired chart]

But I cant seem to get the border to only wrap the bar. Here's the closest I've been able to get:

[image: Actual chart]

Does anyone know how I can do this? Here are my options:

```
highcharts({
chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    plotBorderColor: '#9E9E9E',
    plotBorderWidth: 2,
    height: 200,
    type: 'bar'
},
title: {
    text: null
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tickLength: 0,
    lineColor: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0
},
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tickLength: 0,
    lineColor: 0,
    lineWidth: 0
},
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        borderColor: '#000000'
    }
},
legend: {
    // reversed: true,
    symbolHeight: 0,
    symbolWidth: 0,
    floating: true,
    useHTML: true,
    itemDistance: 10,
    y: -10,
    labelFormatter:
        function() {
            if (this.name === "HIDDEN")
            {
                return '';
            }
            return '<div class="insp360-widgetLegendItemContainer">' +
                    '<div class="insp360-widgetLegendNumber" style="background-color: ' + this.color + '">' + this.yData[0] + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="insp360-widgetLegendName">' + this.name + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        }
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'percent',
        pointWidth: 50
    }
},
series: [
    {
        name: 'New Business',
        data: [chartData['New Business'] || 0],
        color: '#ADD8E6'
    },
    {
        name: 'Re-Underwriting',
        data: [chartData['Re-Underwriting'] || 0],
        color: '#FFBC57'
    },
    {
        name: 'Consultative Visit',
        data: [chartData['Consultative Visit'] || 0],
        color: '#FF5200'
    },
    {
        name: 'Recommendation Check',
        data: [chartData['Recommendation Check'] || 0],
        color: '#B084FF '
    },
    {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [chartData['Other'] || 0],
        color: '#27AC4C'
    }
];
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of things to change to affect this.

working `example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/oyge0jLq/1/

What I updated:

1. You had plotOptions specified twice; combined into one to avoid conflicting values
2. Removed the height declaration from the chart property and moved to html element
3. set the chart margins to force the size of the plot area down and make room for legend and exporting menu
4. set min/max plus minPadding/maxPadding on xAxis
5. removed 'floating' from legend

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much for taking the time to do this. I noticed the duplicate plotOptions later but I should have fixed the question. Thanks again!

Comment: minPadding and maxPadding worked for me